# Silverlight ComboBox Filter - Show All

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

In Silverlight5 with RIA Services, using DomainDataSources.

I have a filter ComboBox which a DataGrid is bound to.

Problem:  How to implement a "Select All" at the top of the combo box - have currently done it by putting a row of ID=0 in the database and using IgnoredValue="0" in the filter

```
    <riaControls:DomainDataSource.FilterDescriptors>
        <riaControls:FilterDescriptor PropertyPath="AccountTypeID" Operator="IsEqualTo" IgnoredValue="0" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.AccountTypeID,
            ElementName=AccountTypeComboBox, FallbackValue=0}"  />
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource.FilterDescriptors>         
</riaControls:DomainDataSource>

<riaControls:DomainDataSource x:Name="AccountTypeDataSource" AutoLoad="True" QueryName="GetAccountTypes" PageSize="15" LoadSize="30">
    <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <domain:xxxDomainContext />
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
</riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

[image]

Would like to manually add the Show All in code after the data has been loaded in the ComboBox

EDIT
Thanks to Martin below I got it working like this:

```
private xxxDomainContext xxxDomainContext;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Load up the AccountType ComboBox - instead of doing it in XAML
        // then add in the Select All via proxy class above
        xxxDomainContext = new xxxDomainContext();
        EntityQuery<AccountType> query = xxxDomainContext.GetAccountTypesQuery();
        LoadOperation loadOperation = xxxDomainContext.Load<AccountType>(query);

        // everything is async so need a callback, otherwise will get an empty collection when trying to iterate over it here
        loadOperation.Completed += AccountTypeLoadOperationCompleted;
```

and

```
 private void AccountTypeLoadOperationCompleted(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // create new proxy class
            var listOfSelectableObjects = new List<SelectableObject<int>>();

            var selectAll = new SelectableObject<int> { Display = "Select All", KeyValue = 0};
            listOfSelectableObjects.Add(selectAll);

            // load values into new list
            foreach (var accountType in xxxDomainContext.AccountTypes)
            {
                var so = new SelectableObject<int>();
                so.Display = accountType.Description;
                so.KeyValue = accountType.AccountTypeID;
                listOfSelectableObjects.Add(so);
            }

            AccountTypeComboBox.ItemsSource = listOfSelectableObjects;
            // Set index to 0 otherwise a blank item will appear at the top and be selected
            AccountTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I have achieved this by creating a proxy class, something like SelectableValue with a display, key and isDefault as shown below:-

```
public class SelectableObject<K>
{
   public string Display { get; set; }
   public K KeyValue { get;set; }
   public bool IsDefaultSelection { get; set; }
}
```

This means that I can then transform the list of items I am selecting from into a `List<SelectableObject<int>>` for example, and optionally add an extra item to that list that is `Display="Select All"` and `IsDefault=true` rather than trying to bind directly to the list.

Hope that helps.